# Is there any way I can change the number of decimal place of a float with .format() using a variable instead of a literal?

Tags: python

I want to make a code so that the user of my code will print e (2.7182818284590452353602874713527) with the decimal places according to the number inputted by the user. This is my code right now.

```
    e = 2.7182818284590452353602874713527 
    dp = int(input("Give a positive integer: "))
    print('e is: {:.dpf}'.format(e)) #the precision needs to be an input from the user
```

Comment: Why not find covert it to string, find the decimal point, and split the string with desired length?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the round() function

```
e = 2.7182818284590452353602874713527 
dp = int(input("Give a positive integer: "))
print('e is: {}'.format(round(e, dp)))
```

Answer (score 1):

`str.format` supports nesting fields:

```
print('e is: {:.{}f}'.format(e, dp))
```

And so do f-strings:

```
f"e is: {e:.{dp}f}"
```

Note that the stdlib already has `math.e` and it's equal to the float you defined.

Answer (score 0):

> *We can create something advanced if you want to use it as in a multiple segments using function and `decimal` package.*

```py
from decimal import Decimal

def decimal_point(varName: str, idp: str, floatVar: float):
    dp = Decimal (idp)
    qe = Decimal (floatVar). quantize (dp)
    return "{} is {}".format(varName, qe)


idp = input("Insert your decimal point range. Ex. ('0.000'): ")     # For example, `0.000`
e = 2.7182818284590452353602874713527
print(decimal_point('e', idp, e))
```

***OUTPUT***

```
Insert your decision point range. Ex. ('0.000'): 0.00
e is 2.71
```